# How do I convert a Vector of ints describing a greyscale image to something displayable by Vulkan?

Tags: c++, vulkan

I'm new to C++ and Vulkan and im trying to learn by rewriting an old Python project of mine in C++. I've created a little app that simulates crystal growth with some random walks over a 2D grid. The final output is a 1D vector of ints `std::vector<int>`, which basically describes a greyscale image, and now im looking to render it. I am using Dear ImGui as a front end to this application and im rendering that using Vulkan as a backend.

I have followed [this tutorial](https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/wiki/Image-Loading-and-Displaying-Examples) to display a jpg but that obviously loads the file from disk. I'm stuck on how I should process my vector to something I can pass into this Vulkan image code. From what I can tell the `stb_load` function returns an unsigned char pointer representing the image? How would I go about writing something to convert my vector to something like that? And is this even the right approach to displaying my data?

Thanks, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You tell Vulkan what the format your data is in. You have the following options:
https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/man/html/VkFormat.html

> VK_FORMAT_R8_UNORM specifies a one-component, 8-bit unsigned normalized format that has a single 8-bit R component.

That means with this format it accepts exactly 8 bytes of data for every pixel inside the image.
As for the shape of the image you can use the following code:

```
VkImageCreateInfo imageInfo{};
imageInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_CREATE_INFO;
imageInfo.imageType = VK_IMAGE_TYPE_2D;
imageInfo.extent.width = static_cast<uint32_t>(texWidth);
imageInfo.extent.height = static_cast<uint32_t>(texHeight);
imageInfo.extent.depth = 1;
imageInfo.mipLevels = 1;
imageInfo.arrayLayers = 1;
```

In your case you'll need to convert your data from `vector<int>` to `vector<unsigned char>`, and then you can upload it with:

```
    if (vkCreateImage(device, &imageInfo, nullptr, &image) != VK_SUCCESS) {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to create image!");
    }
```

(In the above example `image` is supposed to be your data to upload to the GPU)

I suggest for deeper understanding follow this tutorial:

https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Texture_mapping/Images#page_Loading-an-image

Answer (score 1):

Vulkan supports one-channel images where one (unsigned) byte is the intensity of the color, and the format you want is called `VK_FORMAT_R8_UNORM`. Note that while the `R` stands for red, you can render it as you wish in your fragment shader, for example a `vec4(r, r, r, 1)` will render it back as gray.

> And is this even the right approach to displaying my data?

If that's what your image is, a one-channel grayscale image, then that's what it is. Vulkan, like all the other major 3D APIs, treat images more or less like chunks of black-box data, and it is up to you to describe how to sample them correctly.

Comment: Thanks, that helps me understand the formatting of the data, but how do I actually go about converting it to that format in the first place? I think im struggling onhow to actually implement this at every level. I would like to keep all of the code from the example tutorial linked in my main post, but replace the `stbi_load` call with a call to a new func that converts my vector to the exact format that would return.
Swapping the format of the vulkan buffers to 1 channel seems like the simple part at the moment.

Comment: I'm confused, are you asking how to convert a `vector<int>` to `vector<char>`? That has nothing to do with Vulkan, it's basic C++.

Comment: You divide by 16777216, if that's really your question.

Comment: Im not really sure what format vulkan is expecting the image in. If I replace the `stbi_load` with a line that just passes my image vector in then the output is nonesense. Sometimes its an entirely black image, sometimes its got a few red lines on, but it doesnt look like my image data at all.

Comment: I told you, it's not expecting images in any format, you tell it what format you're using.